# Quickest way to assign a PHP variable from an array value that may not exist without error

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style, variable-assignment

This is kind of code golf but I don't feel it's off topic because the issue actually comes up often while I'm working, and keeping code concise and readable is very *on* topic.

```
//$array = ['A' => 'FOO', 'B' => 'BAR'];
//We don't necessarily know what this is

// :-)
$variable = ( isset($array['A']) ) ? $array['A'] : NULL ); 
//We just want $variable to be NULL if the key isn't in the array
```

The works fine but it gets very long with longer variable names etc, and it makes it hard to read big multi-dimensional arrays...

```
[
    'Foo' => 'Bar',
    'Boo' => [
         'FooBarMacFooBar' => ( isset($SomeOtherLongVariable['BooBarMcFooFar']) ) ? $SomeOtherLongVariable['BooBarMcFooFar'] : NULL )
     ] ; 
]
```

Aside from being ugly and hard to read, it's not compliant with the line width maximum (80?) of PSR-2.

The plane won't crash if I do this...

```
[
    'Foo' => 'Bar',
    'Boo' => [
         // THIS WILL THROW AND ERROR NOTICE IF THE KEY DOESN'T EXIST
         'FooBarMacFooBar' => $SomeOtherLongVariable['BooBarMcFooFar']
     ] ; 
]
```

...but if the contents of the array is unknown, it will fill up the logs with error notices about "array key doesn't exist".

Is there a solution to this? (*besides* writing a helper function)

(...and besides using Ruby :-)

Comment: in PHP 7.0 (when it's released) there's the `??` operator or the '[Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)'. In 5.5 you can do `?:` as a ternary which is similar, but will still throw an 'undefiend index' notice. Short of that, no not really.

Comment: how bad is suppressing notices (not errors)? Notices are just suggestions. There really could be a whole lot of other notices added to php considering all the bad practices it would be easy to detect, but the php gods have seemed to have made an arbitrary decision on what is bad enough for a notice.

Comment: @Bsienn: this will trigger a notice as well because an undefined element is passed to the method. Except when the parameter is declared *by reference*, but then the call has the side effect to create the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been bothering PHP developers for years and in PHP 7 the COALESCE operator `??` finally arrived:

#### The new way (starting with PHP 7):

```
$variable = $array['A'] ?? null
```

does exactly the same as your code.

Quoting the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary):

> The coalesce, or `??`, operator is added, which returns the result of its first operand if it exists and is not `NULL`, or else its second operand. This means the `$_GET['mykey'] ?? ""` is completely safe and will not raise an `E_NOTICE`

#### The old way (hackish workaround):

```
$variable = @$array['A'] ?: null;
```

This uses the error suppression operator `@` to silence the notice, and the short ternary operator `?:`. If we only need to set `$variable` to `null` if `$array['A']` is not set, it can be shortened to

```
$variable = @$array['A'];
```

It should be noted that `@` is considered bad practice and I actually feel a bit dirty recommending it, but if you can live with the occasional best practice violation, this is a situation where it does not do harm:

There is only one possible error that can happen in this line (undefined variable/offset). You expect it and handle it gracefully.

Comment: God I hate `@`, but damn if it isn't helpful sometimes.

Comment: Great answer! Is `@` "banned" in PSR-2? I'm not dogmatic about it, but I'm curious if it's going to cause me headaches when I use CS sniffers, etc

Comment: `@` not forbidden in PSR-2 but there are code sniffers that look for it, so it depends on your setup: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/PHP/NoSilencedErrorsSniff.php